# Integral morphism between universally closed and separated schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $f : X\to Y$ be a morphism between schemes over $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{Z}_p)$.

Assume:

- $f$ is integral
- both $X$ and $Y$ are universally closed and separated over $\mathbf{Z}_p$
- $f$ mod $p^n$ is an isomorphism for every $n \ge 0$
- $f_*\mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$

Is $f$ an isomorphism?

**Example** If $X$ and $Y$ were of finite type, they would be proper and so $f$ would be **finite**. The flat locus of $f$ in $X$ is open and nonempty, and then it is $X$. So $f$ is finite flat of degree one, then an isomorphism. (We haven't even used the full assumptions (3) and (4)). The point of this question is: *what if $X$ and $Y$ are **not** of finite type, not even locally?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, by $(1)$ and $(4)$. Any integral morphism is affine by definition. If $f$ is an affine morphism with $f_* \mathcal{O}_X = \mathcal{O}_Y$, then $f$ is clearly an isomorphism.